# How can I make this Parallaleogram shape of Imageview in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[image]

Hello how can i make an imageview which skews image like this?
I tried using skew and matrix but the top was getting cut

Comment: Show what you tried and what the result was.

Comment: Hey thanks, I have made it work now

Comment: Glad to hear. If that's the case, you can either post and accept your own answer so someone with the same question can reference it, or delete the question so it doesn't sit here unanswered.

Comment: @dominicoder oh, sorry, you have already asked to close the question.